# Node Mongo - can't find document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nodes

I'm having trouble to find a document. I have a collection `"registosORS"` with this structure:

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1959d75e0b410558e515be"),
    "sessao" : "1",
    "proprioResponsavel" : "on",
    "outroResponsavel" : "",
    "relacao" : "",
    "valorIndividualmente" : "1",
    "valorInterpessoal" : "1",
    "valorSocialmente" : "1",
    "valorGlobalmente" : "1",
    "cliente_id" : "5a1407c8099ca208e48170a5",
    "email" : "mgoncalves@psi.uminho.pt",
    "data" : 1511610839374
}
```

And I want to find a document by the `cliente_id` value.

Everything works fine but when I get into the `"registosORS"` collection query, the result is `null`.

```
ClientesDAO.prototype.insereDadosOrs = function(dadosORS, date, callback){
    this._connection.open(function(err,mongoClient){
        mongoClient.collection('clientes', function(err,collection){
            collection.findOne({email:dadosORS.email}).then(function(result){

                    var cliente_id = result._id;
                    dadosORS.data = date;
                    mongoClient.collection('registosORS', function(err,collection)                        {
                    collection.insert(dadosORS);

                    dadosSessao = {
                        cliente: cliente_id,
                        data: dadosORS.data,
                        numero : dadosORS.sessao
                    }
```

**I believe here is the problem:**

```
mongoClient.collection('registosORS', function(err,collection){
                        collection.findOne({cliente_id:client_id, data:dadosORS.data}).then(function(result){ 
                        console.log(result);
```

The result is `null`. Where am I failing?

Comment: I believe the values of `client_id` and `dadosORS.data` does not correspond to those stored in your collection. Did you check these values?

Comment: If I make a console.log of those values I get: cilente_id = 5a1407c8099ca208e48170a5
and dadosORS.data = 1511724182264 (is updated as it is a new document of the collection), but the result of the last query is null

Comment: It's confusing because I check it on my side (with different data of course) and it worked. Did you try to check the result with just `cliente_id`?

Comment: well, yes I did console.log(cliente._id) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you solved this?

What should this part resulting in? is it a string of objectID?

```
var cliente_id = result._id;
```

if it should be getting the string of objectID and is used for querying then it will not match your string of cliente_id. The var will result in objectID. It should be parsed to JSON and take the objectID first

```
var cliente_id = result._id.toJSON().$oid
```

Well it's just my speculation. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi dundun, It's not solved and I believe the answer is related with your comment. I'm trying to debug but it's not giving me any log...should I put .$oid? What does it do?

Comment: When I do --- var cliente_id = result._id.toJSON().$oid; ---  it say's client_id is undefined..

Comment: Ok, It worked doing var cliente_id = result._id.toJSON() . Just for curiosity, is it worth to save the object reference or only the string, is there any difference?

Comment: for me it's always better for me to save objectID as object refference since i will not mistake it as a string if i need them as objectID in the future. Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a typo here: `cliente_id:client_id` should be `cliente_id:cliente_id`.

Comment: I've checked and the typo was here and not in the code.